# Netty: how to asynchronously wait when server has no data to return?

Tags: java, netty

For first, thanks for an excellent nio framework - Netty.

Our application includes client and server parts, they are communicating using socket connections and sending protobuf messages. Both the client and the server are written using OIO.
I'm moving the present code to the nio based on netty framework. Currently I have a problem with a server implementation: I haven't found how to process handler using netty's worker thread.

There is the simplified code:

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
  new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  )
);

// Set up the pipeline factory.
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
  public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    final ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    // decoder
    pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(LogServerProto.Request.getDefaultInstance()));
    // Encoder
    pipeline.addLast("protobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    pipeline.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());
    // handler
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler() {
      @Override
      public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent event) throws Exception {
        logger.info("handleClientSocket in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        final MessageLite request = (MessageLite) event.getMessage();
        final MessageLite batch = storage.readBatch(request);
        if (batch != null) {
          event.getChannel().write(batch);
        } else {
          storage.registerListener(new Storage.StorageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSaveBatch() {
              storage.removeListener(this);
              logger.info("Send upstream in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
              event.getChannel().getPipeline().sendUpstream(event);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return pipeline;
  }
});

bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 7000));
```

The server accepts requests (protobuf messages) from the clients. Then server asks the 'storage' for a 'batch'. Storage returns an object or null if no batch is currently available. If batch is  non null - everything work well, but if batch is not available the server should return it to the client when a batch will be added to the storage.
Therefore I'm registering StorageListener which is invoked when a batch is added to the storage (note: batches are added to the storage from a separated thread 'storage-writing-thread'). StorageListener sends upstream using the old 'request' object, pipeline processes it well and my "handler" writes the response (batch) to the channel. Looks like everything is ok, but all these tasks are processed in 'storage-writing-thread' thread. How can I update the listener to process my 'handler' in netty's worker thread in this case?

Comment: Its not clear, If you have many problems, assign question numbers please.

Comment: The question is how the server can wait and write response when the data for response is not available right now. Of course I should not lock a worker thread in a handler. (I tried to do it using a listener which is invoked when data became available, but this listener is invoked not from worker thread. Maybe I should modify my listener in some way or use some other approach w/o any listeners.)

Comment: You can write to the channel from any thread. Is it possible to pass the channel to your StoreListener implementation and then write to the channel using Channels.write(....)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not cleared if I got it correctly, you are looking for a way to give back the result when it is available, to do so, you will need to have a thread which works until the data is available and gives back the results. In your case, the storage class can implement a thread.

You shouldn't wait in working thread and no need to do the response in that thread. To write anything from server to client you will need the have access to channel of client. So all you  need is to pass the channel to your thread as a parameter and send the result from that thread.